# Writing Media Queries in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I am having issues writing my media queries for my website in SCSS. I have created this mixin for each breakpoint on the website and have it compiled using node everytime I save.

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
  @if $breakpoint == phone {
    @media (max-width: 37.5em) {
      @content;
    } //600px
  }
  @if $breakpoint == Tablet-Portrait {
    @media (max-width: 56.25em) {
      @content;
    } //900px
  }
  @if $breakpoint == Tablet-Landscape {
    @media (max-width: 75em) {
      @content;
    } //1200px
  }
  @if $breakpoint == Desktops-small {
    @media (max-width: 90em) {
      @content;
    } //1440px
  }
  @if $breakpoint == Desktops {
    @media (max-width: 112.5em) {
      @content;
    } //1440px
  }
  @if $breakpoint == Big-desktop {
    @media (min-width: 112.5em) {
      @content;
    } //1800px
  }
}
```

I have some of these breakpoints used to change the font size of the website. However, when Tablet-Portrait(900px) is reached, Tablet-Landscape(1200px) is still displayed on the website. Tablet-Landscape seems to be the last breakpoint that is being registered as Tablet-Portrait and Phone breakpoints are not overriding it.

```
html {
  //this defines what 1rem is
  font-size: 62.5%; //10px
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

  @include respond(Tablet-Landscape) {
    //width < 900?
    font-size: 56.25%; //1rem = 9px, 9/16=56.25%
  }
  @include respond(Tablet-Portrait) {
    //width < 600?
    font-size: 50%; //1rem = 8px, 8/16=50%
  }
  @include respond(Big-desktop) {
    // width < 1800?
    font-size: 75%; //1rem = 12px, 12/16=75%
  }
}
```

I have also checked my main css file to see if there were any errors while compiling and I noticed that the breakpoints are included. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

```
*,
x::after,
x::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; }
  @media (max-width: 75em) {
    html {
      font-size: 56.25%; } }
  @media (max-width: 56.25em) {
    html {
      font-size: 50%; } }
  @media (min-width: 112.5em) {
    html {
      font-size: 75%; } }

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777; }
```

Comment: I've just tested this out. I assume your font size is 16px based on your numbers but here it is working https://jsfiddle.net/yhzxLavu/ - I've set colours to easily see the change here is 900px loading the blue colour I've assigned to tablet-portrait https://imgur.com/a/RvMFiwh

Comment: Good Evening Jerrylow, I have edited in the body from my css code my mistake. Forgive me but I dont see any change between what I have coded and yours. The Only change I do see however is body being coded between the html and media styles but that shouldn't affect the webpage. Although, yours does seem to be working.

Comment: Ah yes sorry if I wasn't clear. What I mean to say is, your code as is should be working, so there must be another variable that's affecting it. If you could create a js fiddle that could reproduce the issue that might help.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. There is no problem with the code as we said but its the browser itself. I have been using Google chrome and I have had no problems until now so, I didnt think it would be the issue. I decided to look at the website using Microsoft Edge and apparently it works, lol. Im not a fan of Edge however, I'll probably just switch to FireFox. Thank you for your help however, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah good to know, yes I assume the issue was outside of the code, that being said isolated issues like this could still mean there's something conflicting with the code. A few things that come to mind is if the browser is showing a scrollbar while others aren't. Also you're using ems as the media query metric so this is affected by the font size. If your particular browser has any zoom in/out that would affect metrics too.